# Python Pyfolio PYMC3 ValueError

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I've been running into this problem with pyfolio where I just want to try out the example their github has here: https://quantopian.github.io/pyfolio/notebooks/bayesian/

the program runs through everything and takes awhile to calculate everything but in the end I get this

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 40

here is my current code:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pyfolio as pf
import datetime    

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 1)

stock_rets = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo',start , end)['Adj Close']

out_of_sample = stock_rets.index[-40]

pf.create_bayesian_tear_sheet(stock_rets, live_start_date=out_of_sample)
```

I even tried changing the out_of _sample value to less than 40 and then that sometimes would show an error of:

> Bad initial energy, check any log probabilities that are inf or -inf,
>   nan or very small

any idea what might be causing this problem?

Comment: @merv Thanks! that helped with the error

Comment: Glad that helped! I went ahead and posted that as an answer then, so you can close the question (i.e., accept an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround: Downgrade to PyMC3 v3.4.1

I tried running the tutorial that you indicated and also hit a similar error.  Searching the GitHub repository, I saw [someone reported a similar issue](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio/issues/574). Seems to be a problem with the recent versions of PyMC3 (3.5+).  The suggested workaround is to downgrade to PyMC3 v3.4.1. Hopefully, someone eventually reworks the Pyfolio tutorial (the current version is from summer 2017).